# Find all non negative integers x,y,z so we get a whole square

Tags: number-theory

Find all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N_0}$ so that there exists a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ so that
$$4^x+4^y+4^z=k^2$$.

We can transform this problem to:

Find all $a,b\in\mathbb{N_0}$ so that there exists a $t\in\mathbb{N}$ so that
$$4^a+4^b+1=t^2$$
where $a=x-z, b=y-z, k=2^z \cdot t$.

We see that $3|t^2 \Rightarrow 3|t$ and so we have that $a+b\equiv2 \mod3$.

Looking at $\mod 5$ we can see that both of $a$ and $b$ can't be both even at the same time. So one of them has to be odd.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple#Parametrization_of_primitive_quadruples

Comment: Since $4^x \equiv 1 (\mod 3)$, $3$ is a factor of $k$, so $9$ is a factor of $k^2$. It can be seen that $4^x \equiv 4,7 or 1 (\mod 9)$, so $x=3k+2, y=3k+1$ and $z=3k+1$ is a necessary condition. Not too sure how useful that is though.

Answer (score 1):

seems with $4^a + 4^b + 1 = t^2$ and $a \geq b \geq 1$

```
4  +  4  +  1  = 9
64  +  16  +  1  = 81
1024  +  64  +  1  = 1089
16384  +  256  +  1  = 16641
262144  +  1024  +  1  = 263169
4194304  +  4096  +  1  = 4198401
67108864  +  16384  +  1  = 67125249
1073741824  +  65536  +  1  = 1073807361
17179869184  +  262144  +  1  = 17180131329
274877906944  +  1048576  +  1  = 274878955521
4398046511104  +  4194304  +  1  = 4398050705409
70368744177664  +  16777216  +  1  = 70368760954881
1125899906842624  +  67108864  +  1  = 1125899973951489
18014398509481984  +  268435456  +  1  = 18014398777917441
288230376151711744  +  1073741824  +  1  = 288230377225453569
4611686018427387904  +  4294967296  +  1  = 4611686022722355201
73786976294838206464  +  17179869184  +  1  = 73786976312018075649
1180591620717411303424  +  68719476736  +  1  = 1180591620786130780161
18889465931478580854784  +  274877906944  +  1  = 18889465931753458761729
302231454903657293676544  +  1099511627776  +  1  = 302231454904756805304321
```

we get
$(a,b)$ as  $(1,1),$ $(3,2),$ $(5,3),$ $(7,4),(9,5)$ and generally $(2n-1,n),$ giving
$$  4^{2n-1} + 4^n + 1 = t^2 = \left( 2^{2n-1} + 1 \right)^2 $$

It would appear that the one thing that gives some hope of moving forward is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple#Parametrization_of_primitive_quadruples

Answer (score 0):

write as $4^b(4^{a-b}+1)= (t-1)(t+1) $.
Note that $8|4^a+4^b$. hence each of a and b are $>0$.
hence $4^{b-1}(4^{a-b}+1)=(\frac{t-1}{2})(\frac{t+1}{2})$.
equating the odd parts and even parts we get the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ,

$4^{x}+4^{y}+4^{z}=k^{2}.$

Assume that $x \geq y \geq z$.

It is immediately obvious that $k$ is even.

Let $k=2m$ where $m$ is an integer.

Thus we have,

$4^{x}+4^{y}+4^{z}=4m^{2}$, assuming that $x,y,z \geq 2$, we have,

$4^{x-1}+4^{y-1}+4^{z-1}=m^{2}$, and so we return to our intial equation.

If we repeat this procedure until at least one of $x,y,z$ are $0$, we shall reach the equation you described.

$1+4^{p}+4^{q}=n^{2}$ where $p,q,n$ are arbitrary integers. (*)

WLOG let $p>q$, so we have,

$4^{q}(4^{p-q}+1)=(n-1)(n+1)$.

(*) revealed that $n$ is odd and so $n-1,n+1$ are consecutive even integers. Thus one of these integers must be divisible by a power of $4$, and the other must be of the form $2b$ where $b$ is odd.

And so we have,

$4^{q-1}(4^{p-q}+1)=\frac{(n-1)}{2}\frac{(n+1)}{2}$. (Credit to Samiron)

Equating, the odd and even parts, we are left with,

$\frac{n-1}{2}=4^{q-1} \Rightarrow n=2(4^{q-1})+1,$ and

$\frac{n+1}{2}=4^{p-q}+1 \Rightarrow n=2(4^{p-q})+1$.

Finally,

$4^{p-q}=4^{q-1} \Rightarrow \frac{p+1}{2}=q$

Hence (*) becomes,

$1+4^{p}+4^{\frac{p+1}{2}}=n^{2} \Rightarrow (1+2^{p})^{2}=n^{2}, \Rightarrow n=2p+1$ ,  and we are done.

NB:  If we equate,

$\frac{n-1}{2}=4^{p-q}+1 \Rightarrow n=2(4^{p-q})+3$ and,

$\frac{n+1}{2}=4^{q-1} \Rightarrow n=2(4^{q-1})-1$

Hence,

$2(4^{q-1})-1=2(4^{p-q})+3 \Rightarrow 2(4^{q-1})=2(4^{p-q})+4 \Rightarrow 4^{q-1}=4^{p-q}+2 \Rightarrow 4^{q-1}-4^{p-q}=2$

And so we have a pair of numbers that are multiples of $4$, that differ by $2$. This is clearly not possible. Hence this case yields no solutions.

Comment: Who said that $\frac{n-1}{2}$ has to be a power of $4$? It can also have an odd part of $4^{p-q}+1$.

Comment: Equating those leads to a contradiction. I just didn't want to stretch the argument out any longer. I'll make a comment.

Comment: Like I said, if $4^{p-q}+1$ was prime, we could do that. But if there exist two integers $a,b>1$ so that $a\cdot b= 4^{p-q}+1$ we could write then that $\frac{n-1}{2}=4^{q-1} \cdot a$ and $\frac{n+1}{2}=b$.
We can't say for sure that one of those has to be a power of $4$, just that one contains all of the $q-1$ fours and the other is odd.

Comment: @HeatTheIce You are right. Is there anyway to repair this "solution" ? It just seems unbearably ugly right now. I can't even imagine going any further to be honest.

Comment: @HeatTheIce WHERE did you get the question?

Comment: It's an AOPS article:
http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t177f6h1173228_diophantine_equation